# Does the following piece of writing sound natural?

Tags: grammar

Please have a look at our products. We promise it won't take much time.

Comment: I see nothing unusual or awkward about it. Do you have a specific area of concern?

Answer (score 1):

It looks good. You can also get the message across more quickly (optional):
"Please have a look at our products, it won't take much time."

Comment: the use of a comma to separate the clauses there is incorrect ([comma splice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice)). should be either a semicolon or have a conjunction.

Comment: @xgord As the Wikipedia article you linked says, while comma splices are technically incorrect, they are used to convey a sense of informality, which is the sort of tone that is helpful when reaching out to potential customers. It can feel more conversational in a way that draws people in